# OpenOCD read_bank command asks for more arguments

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, jtag, openocd, stm32f0

We are trying to read out portions of our STM32F0x microcontrollers with OpenOCD, which we also use to program them. However, the `flash read_bank` command doesn't work as documented. Whatever we input, the error is:

```
flash read_bank 0 test.bin: command requires more arguments
```

We invoke it for example by:

```
sudo openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f0x_stlink.cfg -c "init" -c "reset init" -c "flash read_bank 0 test.bin" -c "exit"
```

Other flash operations work as expected, such as:

```
openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f0x_stlink.cfg -c init -c "flash info 0" -c exit
```

or

```
openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f0x_stlink.cfg -c init -c "flash banks" -c exit
```

The command `flash read_bank` seems to be very rarely used. This is at least, was my google search said. Does anybody have an idea on how to use this command?

Answer (score 2):

The `flash read_bank` comannd requires 2 more arguments: Offset and length.

So on a STM32 MCU I you could use

`flash read_bank 0 test.bin 0x8000000 0x4000`

to read the first 16KB of the flash memory.

Remember there is a "help" command in OpenOCD, too.

Comment: Have you tried this? For us, it doesn't matter which and how many arguments we pass. The error is always "requires more arguments":

`sudo openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f0x_stlink.cfg -c "init" -c "reset init" -c "flash read_bank 0 test.bin 0x8000000 0x4000" -c "exit"`

Comment: `flash read_bank 0 test.bin 0x8000000 0x4000: command requires more arguments in procedure 'flash'`

Comment: http://openocd.org/doc/html/Flash-Commands.html#Erasing_002c-Reading_002c-Writing-to-Flash
The documentation says offset and length are optional.

Comment: Check the docs shipped with your OpenOCD version. Mine still has both offsert and length not marked as optional.

Comment: Regardless of the documentation - with or without the offset and length arguments, the command doesn't work and asks for "more arguments". I can add many more arguments and it still asks for more.

Comment: `flash  read_bank 0 test.bin` works in current OpenOCD git, just tested that with my LPC17xx. Note that this is significanly newer than 10.0 release.